# Find a unit vector that is parallel to $\nabla f(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f(x,y)$ is differentiable for all $(x,y),f(x,y)=17$ on the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$, and $\nabla f$ is never zero on the unit circle. For any real number $\theta$, I have to find a unit vector that is parallel to $\nabla f(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$.

My thoughts: When I say this question I feel that it relates to level curves in some way. However not sure how it helps in solving this problem.

Comment: Yes. Now the circle is the level curve of $f$.

Comment: @John So how does that exactly help with this problem. That's where I am having trouble

Comment: Note also that $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to its level curve.

Comment: @John Oh yes. I see

Comment: The gradient is at any given point orthogonal to level curves, and its length is proportional to the "distance" between the level curves at that point.

Comment: @John So how exactly should I do this?

Comment: Can you find a vector which is (1) of unit length, and (2) perpendicular to the circle at $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$? If yes, then that's $\nabla f(\cos \theta, \sin\theta)$.

Comment: @John I'm not sure if I still grasp this concept

Comment: Which parts do you not understand?

Comment: @John The comment you just wrote

Comment: Can you find a vector which is (1) of unit length, and (2) perpendicular to the circle at $(\cos\theta ,\sin \theta)$? (Can you find that?)

Comment: @John Hold on. Let me see if I can do it. I'll try

Comment: @John Would $(\cos 30^{0},\sin 30^{0})$ work?

Comment: Whether or not it is correct depend on your $\theta$. Note that for different $\theta$, you should obtain different vector.

Comment: @sasha I edited the answer to provide a revised interpretation.  If $f$ were a function of $\theta$ alone, as originally written, then $\nabla f$ points along $\hat \theta$.  However, $f=f(r,\theta)$.  On a contour for which $f$ is constant, such as the case here for which $f=17$ on $r=1$,then $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to $\hat \theta$ and thus parallel to $\hat r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is a given function of $\theta$ only, then we have the following:

$\nabla f(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)=\frac{df}{d\theta}\nabla \theta=\frac{df}{d\theta} \hat \theta$

Where $\hat \theta$ is a unit vector that points in the direction of increasing $\theta$.  Thus a unit vector parrallel to $\nabla f$ is indeed $\hat \theta$.  In Cartesian coordinates this unit vector is given by $(-\hat y x+\hat y x)/(x^2+y^2)=-\hat x y+\hat y x$ since we are on the unit circle.

---

However, it seems that $f$ is actually a general function of both $r$ and $\theta$, with $f(1,\theta)=17$.  Then, we note that the directional derivative $\frac{df}{ds}$, where $s$ is the arc length parameter along the unit circle, is zero since $f=17$ is constant on the unit circle.  We can write

$$\frac{df}{ds}=\nabla f\cdot \frac{d\vec r}{ds}=0.$$

But, $\frac{d\vec r}{ds}=\hat \theta$.  Thus, $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to $\hat \theta$ and parallel to $\hat r=\hat x \cos \theta+\hat y \sin \theta$.

Comment: What does the 17 have to do with this though?

Comment: What exactly does that mean? I've never heard that before.

Comment: Can you also explain your first equality?

Comment: @john Sure.  That is the Chain rule.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Don't see why you are using Chain rule here.

Comment: Indeed, your answer is incorrect. It is not possible that the gradient vector $\nabla f$ would be parallel to the level set.

Comment: @john I noted that $f$ is not a function of $\theta$ alone and that your interpretation is correct.  I edited accordingly.  It was my oversight and sincere thanks to you for the catch!

Answer (score -1):

i do not think there is sufficient info to find gradient of f for f(x,y) where x and y are on unit circle.

we only know f(x,y) = 17 on unit circle, but there is no info for f(x,y) infinitely close to the unit circle.